# free OCR processing API in PHP/jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ocr, image-recognition

Is there any free PHP OCR API, that is well documented in PHP, jQuery or JavaScript?

I'm programming a web app for iOS and I'd like to utilize the new photo upload API in iOS 6 safari to use for OCR image processing.

Thanks a ton! :)

(**Edit:** Oh and a Google-Googles like API for image recognition would also suffice, it doesn't have to be OCR, though I would pefer it. :)

Comment: Not for PHP, but free and quite OK is Tesseract.

Comment: @BartFriederichs Yeah but I'd need to accomplish this in PHP or JavaScript or jQuery so this woudn't work... and I want to avoid the `exc` command, because I don't know how to use it. :P

Comment: Sounds like this is a good time to learn!

Comment: @duskwuff yeah... but I thought that there were some native PHP ocr apis...

Comment: There are none that I am aware of. PHP would be an awful language to write an OCR engine with.

Comment: @duskwuff just discovered this: http://ocrsdk.com/ and http://www.ocr-it.com/ in PHP.

Comment: Those are both hosted services -- the actual OCR engine isn't written in PHP. If you're comfortable with paying per image processed, go ahead and use them. They're not cheap, though!

Comment: @duskwuff i know.. :| is there any similar alternative? a bit cheaper?

Comment: @user1935281 Google Cloud Vision. The most powerful OCR and image analysis platform available at the moment. Free for 1000/requests month. $5/1000 requests above that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Tesseract](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) is really simple to use. Someone has even written a PHP wrapper for it so you won't have to deal with the exec() command. Have a look at this here: http://github.com/thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php

Comment: It seems like the PHP wrapper is a really solution, but how do you install ImageMagick? It appears that it is dependent on it...

Comment: do you have access to pecl?

Comment: what is it? do you install pecl or what?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.php it's a tool to install things like imagick

Comment: I have a Godaddy Apache (Linux) server... does it have it built in?

Comment: thats ok. (: Thanks for your help... I marked your answer corect. :)

Comment: It don't contain PoorTest.php file. Any Idea? (Github) https://github.com/thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php/tree/master/vendor

Comment: Found it @ https://github.com/thiagoalessio/poortest

Comment: I really doubt Tesseract will be installed on a shared hosting, if that's what you meant by "Godaddy Apache (Linux) server".

Comment: `tesseract-ocr has Moved!` was no longer available in google code.. Google code was moved !!

Answer (score 2):

You can try http://www.newocr.com/api.php 
It uses REST API.

Comment: [Google Cloud Vision](https://cloud.google.com/vision/) is far, far more accurate than NewOCR

Comment: I hope that was available way way back in 2014.

Comment: What's good for 2022?