# Extract words from an Image and PDF - Laravel

Tags: php, pdf, image-processing, laravel-4, gdlib

is there any way to extract words from scanned images and PDF?
Is there any such library for Laravel as I want to use it for laravel. I have searched a lot for that but did not found any such thing for Laravel. Please let me know if you are aware about it. Every help would be highly appreciated :-). Thanks to all of you in advance !!!!

Comment: You can get OCR software that allows you to read characters from scanned documents as you are scanning them, so maybe it is possible to read a file. This question may push you further along:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284656/free-ocr-processing-api-in-php-jquery-javascript

Comment: Hi friend, Thank you so much :-) I will check it. Thanks for your precious time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing some reading...

- Its possible to read text from scanned images and PDF.
- I too couldn't find libraries for image processing built for explicit use with laravel, but I did find PHP wrappers for the infamous [OpenCV](https://github.com/mgdm/OpenCV-for-PHP) and [TesseractOCR](https://github.com/thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php), maybe they'll help.

Some useful readings:

- [TesseractOCR for PHP on Windows](http://thiagoalessio.me/tesseractocr-for-php-on-windows/)
- [How to extract text from image using openCV or OCR tesseract?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616234/how-to-extract-text-from-image-using-opencv-or-ocr-tesseract)

#### Edit:

- [Read text from images with tesseract using PHP tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/ocr-in-php-read-text-from-images-with-tesseract/)

Comment: Will check it out, cheers for the info.

Comment: Hi Friend Thanks for providing wonderful documentation, I'm gonna check this out :-)