# Image Manipulator LARAVEL

Tags: image, laravel, laravel-5, package

I need  a image manipulator for laravel but with only a few features:

Delete text from image (White Brush (?) ) 
Add text with a specific font. 
Add other images in the image..

if is possible, a live view!

Any ideas of some package ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract words from an Image and PDF - Laravel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33303389/extract-words-from-an-image-and-pdf-laravel)

Answer (score 3):

Check out most popular image manipulation package [Intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io).

> Intervention Image is an open source PHP image handling and
>   manipulation library. It provides an easier and expressive way to
>   create, edit, and compose images and supports currently the two most
>   common image processing libraries GD Library and Imagick.

You can insert images into main image with [`insert()`](http://image.intervention.io/api/insert) method, add custom text to image with [`text()`](http://image.intervention.io/api/text) method etc.